# C# Validation control

Tags: asp.net-3.5

Is it possible to use `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` and `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` for a single textbox.

Comment: You can always try that. This, for one, will take much less time than you spend waiting for an answer on SO. Plus, I believe that a properly constructed regex will disallow empty text to be entered in a textbox, thus rendering `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` unneccessary.

Comment: It may not be necessary in absolute terms, but if it means you can provide more meaningful error messages to the user i.e. distinguishing in the validation text between "required but missing" and "supplied but wrong" then it may be desirable. You're absolutely right about trying being faster than asking in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. Just put them both on your page and set their controlToValidate to the same control

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just bind both to the same TextBox/whatever control you want to validate.